# How can I get 1, 2 or maybe 3 values split by / using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Lets say we have the url www.stackoverflow.com/hello/you/guys
How can I get each value after / (if second and third slash) as a variable? (like: a=hello, b=you, c=guys)

f I only have one / this works but I can't figure how to do if there are more /:s
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ0-9_-]+) /index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
```

But a better way is parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

**UPDATE:**

use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

.htaccess:

```
# Rewrite all URLs to index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

index.php:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$params = explode('/', $url['path']);
var_dump($params);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) ... can you as well give me an exampel using: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] as you suggested?

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try as well :). Btw, I needed to add / before index.php in your first example to make it work.

Comment: @user3214817 You can just added ``RewriteBase /`` to beginning of your .htaccess